# How to edit fields for only one specific deck in Anki?

Tags: anki

Is there any way to edit fields for only one specific deck in Anki?

[image]

When adding a new field to one Anki deck, Anki automatically edits all of the other decks too. How can I edit only the fields of one specific deck?

Answer (score 1):

The technically correct but unhelpful answer is "you cannot". The fields and their names are a property of the [note type](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#notes-&-fields), not the [deck](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#decks).

What you will have to do is [create a new note type](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#adding-a-note-type) and [change](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#browsermisc) (search there for *Change Note Type*) everything in that deck to the new type. Then you will be able to edit the fields for just that deck.

Comment: Hi Andrew, would be great to provide [context around the links](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) you have provided in your answer, in the event the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.